# Number format and rounding in php

Tags: php

```
xx.01 and xx.02 go to xx.00
xx.03 and xx.04 go to xx.05
xx.06 and xx.07 go to xx.05
xx.08 and xx.09 go to xx.10
xx.11 and xx.12 go to xx.10
xx.13 and xx.14 go to xx.15
```

I need the below format behind the dot.

```
0.05 / 0.10 / 0.15/ 0.20 / 0.25 / 0.30 / 0.35 / 0.40 etc….
```

Can anyone give me a function in PHP to convert the number after the dot to the expected value?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research?

Comment: round() , do you want to round off

Comment: I have used the round() function but not getting the proper result which i want. Have any logic then plz let me know i will built. @Wasim

Comment: When the system told you that a question with your title already exists, the solution was to write a better title, not misspell "number" as "numbar." Also, really, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

```
function soRound($a, $to=0.05) {
  return round($a / $to) * $to ;
}
```

This rounds as you describe with no default second argument

i.e `soRound(1.07);` returns `1.05`

Comment: Thanks alot. It is possible from 1.68 to 1.70

Comment: so 1.70 instead of 1.7 ? use `number_format($number,2)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to round, but you can only use `round` to round to the nearest tenth. You want to round to the nearest twentieth. The solution is to multiply by 2, round to the nearest tenth, divide by 2, and format as needed:

```
$data = [0, 0.01, 0.07, 0.09, 1.56, 1.73, 3.14159];

foreach ($data as $num) {
    $num = round($num * 2, 1) / 2;
    echo number_format($num, 2) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0.00
0.00
0.05
0.10
1.55
1.75
3.15
```

[**Here's a working demo**](http://ideone.com/TUld0s).

In function form:

```
function roundToNearest05($num) {
    return round($num * 2, 1) / 2;
}

// or, more generically, this:

function roundTo($num = 0, $nearest = 0.05) {
    return round($num / $nearest) * $nearest;
}
```